# Gnome-Tweaks it's broken with the new Ubuntu Realese. Please help

Tags: apt, gnome, package-management, dependencies, libraries

just then I was performing another new Ubuntu 21.04 installation, and today (not this error few weeks ago) I get install gnome-tweaks and cannot be possible, because it say that I have the unmet dependencies. If I try to install it by terminal, it comes out the following error in my language (I translated below):

```
I seguenti pacchetti hanno dipendenze non soddisfatte:
gnome-shell-extension-prefs : 
Dipende: gnome-shell (= 3.38.4-1ubuntu3~21.04.1) ma la versione 3.38.4-1ubuntu2 sta per essere installata
Dipende: gnome-shell-common (= 3.38.4-1ubuntu3~21.04.1) ma la versione 3.38.4-1ubuntu2 sta per essere installata
E: Impossibile correggere i problemi, ci sono pacchetti danneggiati bloccati.
```

I try to translate in English, as below:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
gnome-shell-extension-prefs:
Depends: gnome-shell (= 3.38.4-1ubuntu3 ~ 21.04.1) but version 3.38.4-1ubuntu2 is about to be installed
Depends: gnome-shell-common (= 3.38.4-1ubuntu3 ~ 21.04.1) but version 3.38.4-1ubuntu2 is about to be installed
E: Unable to fix problems, there are bad packages blocked.
```

So, seems that `gnome-shell` and `gnome-shell-common` have got a lib **version 3** `3.38.4-1ubuntu3` but `gnome-tweaks` it's based on the following lib **version 2** `3.38.4-1ubuntu2`.

Anyone knows how to fix or what is going on here?

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add the output of `sudo apt update`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot @muru for upgrade my post and added the new upgrades, `sudo apt update` now gives me the two libs fix and I performed the upgrade.

It starts to work everything again :).